# Antonym for atmosphere?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, antonyms

To be used for either meaning (air around the planet, or aura/feeling of a location) of the word atmosphere.

Earth and vacuum are the closest I can think of for air atmosphere, but all I can come up with for aura is to describe it using negatives.

Are there true antonyms for either definition of atmosphere?

Comment: Could you give us an example of this word in a sentence? I don't understand how the atmosphere of a location could have an antonym. Vacuum is a perfectly good antonym for the sense of gases surrounding a planet.

Comment: I'm not sure what would conceptually be an antonym of either. In general, there aren't antonyms for concrete nouns. What's the opposite of a car? Lack of a car? Vacuum is good for lack of atmosphere/air, but I'm not sure there is a single word for lack of atmosphere/aura. Void?

Comment: I don't think you understand what "antonym" means. It's a fairly rare phenomenon and requires a presupposed graded scale. Most words don't have such a scale.

Comment: Antonym - A word having an opposite meaning to another word, as I understand it. This was just a question that came out of a discussion on something unrelated with a friend.

Comment: What, precisely, does "opposite" mean? It presupposes a graded scale like _freezing ~ cold ~ cool ~ tepid ~ warm ~ hot ~ boiling_. In what dimensional scale does _Atmosphere_ oppose ... what? _Hydrosphere? Lithosphere? Magnetosphere?_

Comment: What's an antonym for sausage dog?

Comment: @JohnP The problem is that the appropriate antonym of a word can vary depending on context. In what respect is an atmosphere significant that you would expect an antonym to invert?

Comment: @user867 Not so. The problem is that there is no antonym to 'atmosphere' (any more than 'sausage dog') – as John Lawler implies, there is no graded scale on which 'atmosphere' (or rather the referent, the actual atmosphere) sits at one end (when we _might_ find an antonym at the other – like powerful - - - weak – and _then_ we can worry about appropriate context (powerful tea?))

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I know that and you know that, but the OP didn't seem to get it from the comments that explicitly said as much. I therefore made a query designed to make the OP to reconsider the basis of his question, in the hopes that he would thereby realize why that question is nonsensical. I couldn't think of a way to signpost this fact to other users without giving the game away to my intended target, though. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This question is not clear and rightly closed. I feel that there are certain words that do not have an antonym. What's the antonym of _coffee_? Besides, it depends on the context. The antonym of _right_ can be both 'wrong' and 'left' depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

Most antonyms related to "atmosphere" are going to revolve around *specific* atmospheres:

> The atmosphere is inhabitable. — The atmosphere is uninhabitable.
>
> The atmosphere/aura in here is electric! — The atmosphere/aura in here is dead.

The opposite of having an atmosphere is simply not having one. This could also be described as "vacuum":

> That moon has no atmosphere. — That moon has an atmosphere.
>
> That moon is surrounded by an atmosphere. — That moon is surrounded by a vacuum.

There is one other concept that could work as an antonym of atmosphere and this relates to the idea of the atmosphere as a location:

> The creature lives in the atmosphere of that moon.
>
> The creature lives on the surface of that moon.
>
> The creature lives in space near that moon.

In this sense, both "surface" and "space" could be considered antonyms but it would technically be more accurate to say that "atmosphere" has no antonym.

In short, "vacuum" could be used as an antonym given the appropriate context and usage but it only truly relates to the air/environment surrounding a celestial body. I can see a rather weak argument for "surface" or "space" but it is stretching the definition of "antonym" quite a bit. There is no appropriate antonym for aura unless you choose to define one as such for the sake of a story:

> Alice was surrounded by a tangible atmosphere/aura but Bob only had vacuum.

Comment: mmm, I don't think surface and space are antonyms of atmosphere in any sense.  The only word in your answer that fits is "vacuum" and that's not really used correctly either.  Something is *in* a vacuum, not *surrounded* by a vacuum.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: The first sentence on Wikipedia's article on [atmosphere of the Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_the_Moon) uses "surrounded by vacuum". I suppose I added "a" and can remove that if you think it matters enough. And I explicitly mentioned that "surface" and "space" really aren't antonyms. Is there a way I can make it more clear in the post?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about vacuum usage.  As to the other issue, I guess I'm getting a mixed message because of this sentence: "In short, "surface", "space" and "vacuum" **could all be used as antonym** given the appropriate context and usage but all three of these relate to the air/environment surrounding a celestial body."

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll edit that part to be a little more clear.

Answer (score -1):

ambience for "feeling of a location"

Comment: Wouldn't *ambience* be a synonym? My dictionary defines it as "ambience -- atmosphere: the typical atmosphere or mood of a place"

Answer (score -2):

Used figuratively, if a place has *[an] atmosphere*, it has some distinctive (but not necessarily explicitly specified) characteristic or ambience. Some other place lacking any such characteristic could thus be described as...

> [**nondescript**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nondescript) *- having no special or interesting qualities, parts, etc. : typical and uninteresting*

Comment: Do note that you can still say "This place has a nondescript atmosphere." Wouldn't it more accurate to say that "nondescript" is really an antonym of a particular *type* of atmosphere?

Comment: @MrHen: Personally, I'd say that "nondescript atmosphere" is a fairly odd thing to say, given that anyone who used it would (presumably) mean *"This place has **no** atmosphere."*

Comment: Well, it would literally mean "this place has [no special] [mood or tone]." You could just as easily describe a room with a nondescript decor.

Comment: @MrHen: Obviously, the interpretation of figurative usages like this is somewhat subjective. But I would point out that Google Books claims just 70 instances of *nondescript atmosphere*, against  10,300 for ***distinctive** atmosphere*. That's about 150:1 for "atmosphere" being associated with "special or interesting qualities", whereas the ratio for *distinctive/nondescript **decor*** is less than 10:1 ("decor" has no particular "interesting" associations, so that ratio simply reflects the relative prevalence of the two adjectives).

Comment: I don't see how Google Books hit counts are relevant. We aren't talking about frequency of usage; we are talking about whether something is an antonym.

Comment: @MrHen: And as both my answer and my comments should make clear, I *personally* think that (even unqualified), figurative *atmosphere* has strong connotations of *distinctive*. If you don't accept that, and can't see how those GB counts support my position, I doubt there's anything more I can say about it.

Comment: Your final comment isn't really addressing the question in my original comment. We can take this up in [chat] if you still aren't understanding my point.